# MinGW Distro installation issue

Tags: c++, mingw

I'm trying to install MinGW distro following the steps here: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html#install

But, when I try to run: gcc --version

at my command line I get the following:

'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Why is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up your **`PATH`** environment variable so that the command interpreter finds the `gcc` program.

E.g. (since you’re working in the Windows [cmd.exe] command interpreter)

> set path=%path%;%programfiles%\mingw\bin

You have to use the path that applies to your system and your installation of the compiler.

You can set up a more permanent path via the Environment button in the System applet in the Control Panel. You can also do it more low level via the registry (e.g. command `regedit`). And in other ways.

By the way,

*for C++ programming use `g++`, do not use `gcc` directly.*

At least if you want to avoid trouble. Of course you can do manually what `g++` does. But much easier to use `g++`; that’s what it’s for.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I did that actually, and added this to the PATH environment variable: C:\MinGW\bin, but still the same.

Comment: Check your path by `echo %path%`. Also check that it refers to correct directory (folder). To do the latter, try to `cd` to that directory.

Comment: This is what I got when running echo %path%: C:\Ruby192\bin; C:\MinGW\bin

Comment: Remove the space. And did you check (e.g. via `cd`) that you actually have a `c:\mingw\bin` directory?

Comment: Is there really a space between `C:\Ruby192\bin;` and `C:\MinGW\bin`? I don't know if that matters, but I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Well, I think you tried that before I added "Remove the space" at front of previous comment. Remove the space. Now does it work?

Comment: @SWE: Please type each of the following commands into the console and hit enter after each and tell us what happens. `c:` ENTER `cd \mingw` ENTER `cd bin` ENTER `dir gcc.exe` ENTER `gcc --version` ENTER `cd ..` ENTER `gcc --version` ENTER.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. I actually went now with "Cygwin".

Answer (score 0):

The command prompt cannot find the program 'gcc'. It's most likely because you have something wrong with the environment variable. If the pathname given in the environment variable is at all incorrect or non-existent (if you have the folder in another place), then command prompt will not be able to find it.